# Remove anchor tag only, but to keep inner html?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to write jquery, to remove the anchor tag properties, and add other properties... I cannot make direct changes inside the html, so have to do it through jquery. How can I do it?

```
<span id="TabnavTabLogoTextId" class="navTabButton navTabThemeButton" title="Microsoft Dynamics CRM Go to home page.">
    <a title="Microsoft Dynamics CRM Go to home page." class="navTabButtonLink" onkeypress="return true;" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">
        <span id="navTabLogoTextId" class="navTabLogoTextThemeImage">
            <img alt="Microsoft Dynamics CRM Microsoft Dynamics CRM" unselectable="on" src="/NFDIL/%7B636004438060001088%7D/WebResources/pcl_SiteLogo.png">
        </span>
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what youy want to achieve, but if you simply want to remove the `a` element, but keep it's children use `unwrap()`: `$('#navTabLogoTextId').unwrap();`.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned.. I dont want to remove the tag, but i want to remove its properties..

Comment: You did not 'clearly mention' which properties though, hence all the downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `removeAttr` to remove all attributes of anchor.

```
$('a').removeAttr('title,class,onkeypress,onclick,href,unselectable');
```

Use this when you want to add attributes back to `<a>`

```
$('a').attr('title','//yourtitle'); // and so on like this
```

Comment: how can i add attributes back to the anchor tag?

Comment: $document.ready(function(){
$("#TabnavTabLogoTextId").children().removeAttr('onclick,href');
$("#TabnavTabLogoTextId").children().attr('onclick','alert(\'a\')');
$("#TabnavTabLogoTextId").children().attr('href','#');
});

This is not working....